# Return only repeated records from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I need to return only rows that are repeated lets say 30 times in my database. I added this COUNT function after SELECT but honestly have no idea what to do as a next step. Could someone advice me please?

```
$variable = "SELECT COUNT(mail.h_datetime, sent.f_mail_subject, sent.f_mail_content)"
        ."FROM mail"
        ."INNER JOIN sent ON mail.h_id = sent.e_mail_templates_id"
        ."WHERE f_template_type =  'newsletter'";
```

Comment: *"I added this COUNT function after SELECT"* - where's this?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ok, I have added it to this code exactly like I have it  in my file now

Comment: Look into the 'HAVING' clause, of SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY` all selected rows. Use `HAVING` to only return rows that appear at least 30 times.

```
SELECT mail.h_datetime, sent.f_mail_subject, sent.f_mail_content
FROM mail
    INNER JOIN sent ON mail.h_id = sent.e_mail_templates_id
WHERE f_template_type =  'newsletter'
GROUP BY mail.h_datetime, sent.f_mail_subject, sent.f_mail_content
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 30
```

Comment: Thank you, I am giving best answer for this!
Could you please explain me, why do i need GROUP BY here? Its pretty much complicated

Comment: The GROUP BY is there to specify how to group rows together. In this case you want datetime, subject and contents together. Count the number of each combination, use HAVING to only return combinations that occur at least 30 times.